# How to delete specific row from sqlite database and bind with qlineedit?

Tags: sql, qt, sqlite, prepared-statement

I can delete specific rows using manual SQL query command. But can not delete from `QLineEdit`. How to bind with `QLineEdit`?

Here is my code:

```
person_name = ui->txt_UserName->text ();
mobile_number = ui->txt_Pass->text ();

//delete values
QString deleteStatement = "DELETE FROM phonebook_info WHERE  user_name = ':person_name'";
query->bindValue (":person_name", person_name);

query->exec (deleteStatement);

if(query->exec ()){
    QMessageBox::information (this, "Information!", "Row Deleted.", QMessageBox::Ok);
    ui->statusBar->showMessage ("Row Deleted.");
} else {
    QMessageBox::critical (this, "Information!", "Row not Deleted.", QMessageBox::Ok);
    ui->statusBar->showMessage ("Row not Deleted.");
}
```

query executed but not delete. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try omit the parenthesis around `:person_name`. Prepared query should do this for you

Comment: Also you have to prepare the query before binding variables.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax doesn't look right and you call `query->exec()` twice. This is how you should run the prepared statement:

```
QSqlQuery query = new QSqlQuery(databaseInstance);
bool ok = query->prepare(deleteStatement);
if (!ok) {
    qWarning() << "SQL error:" << deleteStatement;
}
query->bindValue(":person_name", person_name);
query->exec();
```

Comment: Sorry. Doesn't work. My query statement is right or wrong ?

Comment: Thanks. My mistake. It works and understand. Thanks again.